# How can I add stop loss and take profit section in Tradingview alarm message. I guess this can be done using plot

Tags: pine-script

How can I add stop loss and take profit section in Tradingview alarm message?

I want to use it in study app, not in strategy

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plot your TP and SL like below:

```
plot(tp_price, "TP")
plot(sl_price, "SL")
```

Then you can use the name of the plots in your alert message:

```
alertcondition(your_condition_here, "Alert Title", "TP: {{plot("TP")}}, SL: {{plot("SL")}}"
```

See [this](https://www.tradingview.com/support/solutions/43000531021-how-to-use-a-variable-value-in-alert/) for more details.